# DDD/CQRS for composite .NET app with multiple databases

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'll admit that I am still quite a newbie with DDD and even more so with CQRS.  I also realize that DDD and/or CQRS might not be the right approach to every problem.  Nevertheless, I like the principals but have some questions in the context of a current project.

The solution is a simulator that generates performance data based on the current configuration.  Administrators can create and modify the specifications for simulations.  Testers set some environmental conditions and run the simulator.  The results are captured, aggregated and reported.

The solution consists of 3 component areas each with their own use-cases, domain logic and supporting data structure.  As a result, a modular designed seems appealing as a way to segregate logic and separate concerns.

1. The first area would be the administrative aspect which allows users to create and modify the specifications. This would be a CRUD heavy 'module'.
2. The second area would be for executing the simulations. The domain model would be similar to the first area but optimized for executing the simulation as opposed to providing a convenient model for editing.
3. The third area is reporting.

From this I believe that I have three Bounding Contexts, yes? I have three clear entry points into the application, three sets of domain logic and three different data models to support the domain logic.

My first instinct is to follow these lines and create three modules (assemblies) that encapsulate the domain layer for each area.  Should I also have three separate databases? Maybe more than three to support write versus read?

I gather this may be preferred for CQRS but am not sure how to go about it. It appears to me that CQRS suggests a set of back-end processes that move data around. But if that's the case, and data persistence is cross-cutting (as DDD suggests), then doesn't my data access code need awareness of all of the domain objects?  If so, then is there a benefit to having separate modules?

Finally, something I failed to mention earlier is that specifications are considered 'drafts' until published, which makes then available for simulation.  My PublishingService needs to have knowledge of the domain model for both the first and second areas so that when it responds to the SpecificationPublishedEvent, it can read the specification, translate the model and persist it for execution.  This makes me think I don't have three bounding contexts after all.  Or am I missing something in my analysis?

Comment: Whats the PublishingService again? Is this the service that executes the simulations? Or is the PublishingService the same thing as the event publisher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a modular UI for this, but I don't see three separate domains in what you are describing necessarily.

First off, in CQRS reporting is not directly a domain model concern, it is a facet of the separated Read Model which takes on the responsibility of presenting the domain state optimized for reporting.

Second just because you have different things happening in the domain is not necessarily a reason to bound them away from each other.  I'd take a read through the blue DDD book to get a bit better feel for what BCs look like.

I don't really understand your domain well enough but I'll try to give some general suggestions.

Start with where you talked about your PublishingService.  I see a Specification aggregate root which takes a few commands that probably look like CreateNewSpecification, UpdateSpecification and PublishSpecification.

The events look similar and probably feel redundant: SpecificationCreated, SpecificationUpdated, SpecificationPublished.  Which kind of sucks but a CRUD heavy model doesn't have very interesting behaviors.  I'd also suggest finding an automated way to deal with model/schema changes on this aggregate which will be tedious if you don't use code generation, or handle the changes in a dynamic *emphasized text*way that doesn't require you to build new events each time.

Also you might just consider not using event sourcing for such an aggregate root since it is so CRUD heavy.

The second thing you describe seems to be about starting a simulation which will run based on a Specification and produce data during that simulation (I assume).  An event driven architecture makes sense here to decouple updating the reporting data from the process that is producing the data.  This has huge benefits if you are producing large amounts of data to process.

However it doesn't sound like a Simulation is necessarily the kind of AR that would benefit from Event Sourcing either.  For a couple reasons:

1. Simulation really takes only one Command which is something like StartSimulation
2. Simulation then produces events over it's life-time which represent what is happening internally with the simulation
3. Simulation doesn't seem to ever receive any other Commands that could depend on the current state of the Simulation
4. Simulation is not interacted with by multiple clients/users simultaneously and as we pointed out it isn't really interacted with at all

In general, domain modeling is very specific to each individual project so it's hard to give you all the information you need to build your domain model.  It will come as a result of spending a great deal of time trying to understand your user's needs and the problem they are trying to solve with the software.  It likely will go through multiple refinements as you develop insights into their process.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, this topic had become stale so I only now saw your response. A quick follow-up, though. What do you mean by "which takes a few commands" when you say "I see a Specification aggregate root which takes a few commands..."?